# Объединение CSV файлов

Tags: powershell, csv

Есть два CSV файла. Первый:

```
"Column1","Column2"
"Name1","String1"
"Name2","String2"
"Name3","String3"
```

И второй:

```
"Column1","Column3"
"Name1","Date1"
"Name2","Date2"
"Name3","Date3"
```

Суть задачи состоит в том, чтобы объединить оба файла таким образом, чтобы получилось:

```
"Column1","Column2","Column3"
"Name1","String1","Date1"
"Name2","String2","Date2"
"Name3","String3","Date3"
```

Какие командлеты нужно использовать? `Import-Csv`? Как вообще добиться нужного результата?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно понимать, что в контексте подразумевалось что оба CSV содержат одинаковое количество строк, так? Import-Csv в данном случае не товарищ. Лучше прочитать оба файла с помощью командлета Get-Content, а полученные массивы строк объединить методом Zip, определенного в Linq.Enumerable, правда для этого придется задействовать обобщенный делегат. В переводе на PS это будет выглядеть так.

```
[Linq.Enumerable]::Zip(
   (Get-Content .\1.csv), (Get-Content .\2.csv),
   [Func[Object, Object, Object[]]]{($args.Split(',') | Select-Object -Unique) -join ','}) |
ConvertFrom-Csv | Export-Csv out.csv
```

Однако стоит иметь в виду, что корректность подобного подхода возможна на поздних версиях PS, таких как 5 или 6, в ранних невозможно сказать однозначно. Если же требуется решение именно для ранних версий, наверное, лучшим вариантом будет обойти массивы строк в цикле.

Comment: Нет, речь как раз была о последних версиях. В моем случае это шестая версия. Просто забыла об этом написать.